# Space of convergent sequences is separable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $c$ be the space of all convergent real sequences, with the sup norm. Show that this space is separable.

My attempt:

I've considered the set of sequences with rational entries that are eventually constant, I've also shown that this set is countable but I'm stuck as to how to show that it's dense in $c$

Comment: For $x = (x_n) \in c, \alpha := \lim x_n,$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n - \alpha| < \epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. So take $y = (x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_N, \alpha, \alpha, \ldots)$ and check that $\|y-x\|_{\infty} < \epsilon$.

Comment: I get the reasoning but you see that the $x_n$ and $\alpha$ arenot necessarily rational numbers right?

Comment: The point is that there's an eventually constant rational sequence that starts arbitrarily close to $x_1$ through $x_N$ and then is constant at a rational number arbitrarily close to $\alpha$.  So you have an eventually constant rational sequence that's arbitrarily close (in the sup norm) to the given sequence.

Comment: By your definition $x_n$ is rational and since is eventually constant, $\alpha$ is an element of the sequence, hence, is rational.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a convergent sequence with limit $L$.

Given any $\epsilon >0:$

(1). Take $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $\forall n>n_0\,(|x_n-L|<\epsilon /2\,).$

(2). Take $M\in \Bbb Q$ such that $|L-M|<\epsilon /2,$ and for $n>n_0$ let $q_n=M.$

(3). For $n\le n_0,$ take $q_n\in\Bbb Q$ such that $|x_n-q_n|<\epsilon.$

Then  $(q_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is an eventually constant rational sequence and $\forall n\,(\,|x_n-q_n|<\epsilon \,).$